# Direct Anonymous Attestation

Tags: certificates

Could anyone explain me Direct Anonymous Attestation in general terms. I have been trying to read the [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1030103) but I really cannot seem to get my head around it. It may seem like a dumb question but I am not a cryptographer and would appreciate it if anyone could explain it simple terms.

Comment: Could you please explain more precisely what you do not understand (and what you do) in the related paper? Otherwise I think your question is off topic.

Comment: Try this side: http://www.research.ibm.com/labs/zurich/idemix/whatitdoes.html

Comment: Were you able to find a simple explanation of the working ?